# Latex tabular input in epslatex terminal of gnuplot makes border disappear

Tags: latex, gnuplot, eps

Suppose I have the file `table.tex`

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

This basically is a 2 by 2 table with some numbers.

I can compile it like that, and see borders on any side of the table

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{table.tex}
\end{document}
```

Now I have the following `gnuplot` script (tested with 4.6.2 and 4.6.5)

```
set terminal epslatex standalone solid
set output "out.tex"
set label '\input{table.tex}' at 1,1
plot x
```

Then I get the following
[image: Sample output]

In other words, my borders have disappeared. How can I solve that?

Comment: At close voter: this is a `gnuplot` question rather than a `latex` question. Therefore, in my opinion it is much more suitable here than on tex.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a limitation of the `minimal` documentclass which is used by the `epslatex` terminal in `standalone` mode. The following works fine:

Main file `out-main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{out}
\end{document}
```

and the gnuplot script

```
set terminal epslatex solid

set output "out.tex"
set label at 1,1 '\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \
\hline \
1 & 2 \\ \hline \
3 & 4 \\ \hline \
\end{tabular}'

plot x
set output
system("latex out-main && dvips out-main && ps2pdf out-main.ps")
```

gives

[image]

Comment: The only downside of this approach, is that the resulting `eps` file in my case, has a different font-size now. Any idea where that comes from?

Comment: I do have `font "" 8` in my `set terminal epslatex` line.

Comment: All `font` options but the combination `standalone font ...` are ignored by the epslatex terminal. To change the font size you must change your `out-main.tex` file accordingly.